Changing a Backup using xcopy to one using robocopy in Win 11
In a Windows 11 Pro and Office 21 Pro environment on a Lenovo 13th Gen, Intel i7-55U, 16GB, 64 bit, Notebook, are there any pitfalls in an incremental copy of Dir/files from external drive F to External Drive E if the last copy was executed with xcopy and the next and all future copies will use robocopy?
Are any different switches needed?

None whatsoever - although the switches are entirely different, and robocopy has a useful mirror feature ensuring source and destination are the same - robocopy also defaults to waiting indefinitely if the file is busy, whereas xcopy with the /c switch skips

@JohnnyVegas Please convert your comment into an answer.

To piggy back on @JohnnyVegas, RoboCopy can also monitor a source directory for changes and auto mirror the source directory - to do so, you may want to use a script and a task in Task Scheduler [taskschd.msc]. I use this method to keep exact backups of OneNote and Outlook data files, and the files needed are on my GitHub. I can create an answer for this method in a few days, but don't have time at the moment.

None whatsoever - although the switches are entirely different, and robocopy has a useful mirror feature ensuring source and destination are the same - robocopy also defaults to waiting indefinitely if the file is busy, whereas xcopy with the /c switch skips.
